# wavesurfer getPeaks is returning an empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, waveform

i`m using **wavesurfer.js** a customizable audio waveform visualization (https://wavesurfer-js.org/), from the following library

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.2.3/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
```

even including the minified script: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js"></script>` the problem remains

below is my code where i was returning the audio peaks in an interval, 3 days ago it was working normally, until yesterday it was working normally,

today it just stopped returning some value and is returning an empty array

if i remove the backend option from the setup it does not render my audio on the screen

```
  var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
      container: document.querySelector('#waveform'),
      // backend: 'MediaElement',
      waveColor: 'black',
      progressColor: 'gray',
    });
```

**I will explain my application better, I am sending a file through a form so I pass the file (path)**

```
$audio = asset('original/'. $file->getClientOriginalName ());
```

to the return view

```
return view ('result')-> with('audio', $audio);
```

and i'm rendering it this way

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
      container: document.querySelector('#waveform'),
      backend: 'MediaElement',
      waveColor: 'black',
      progressColor: 'gray',
    });

    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio')

    audioElement.autoplay = true
    audioElement.loop = true
    audioElement.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
    audioElement.src = '{!! $audio !!}'

    wavesurfer.load(audioElement);

    wavesurfer.on('ready', function() {

      var length  = wavesurfer.getDuration();
      var start   = 0;
      var end     = length;

      console.log(wavesurfer.backend.getPeaks(length, start, end));

    });

  });
```

and in this way, using the backend when creating the WaveSurfer the waves are rendered on screen, if I remove them, the peaks appear but the waves on the screen do not

could someone tell me what am i doing wrong? I spent 6 hours today trying to solve it and i couldn't

how should i install or import the library to use it? thank you, i'll wait

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you remove this line from the config:

```
backend: 'MediaElement',
```

Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: document.querySelector('#waveform'),
    // backend: 'MediaElement',
    waveColor: 'black',
    progressColor: 'gray'
  });
  
  wavesurfer.load('http://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3');

  wavesurfer.on('ready', function() {
    var length = 300;
    var start = 0;
    var end = 300;
    console.log(wavesurfer.backend.getPeaks(length, start, end));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js"></script>

<div id="waveform"></div>
```

**Update**

From the [API documentation](https://wavesurfer-js.org/api/index.html):

> Can the audio start playing before the waveform is drawn?
>
> Yes, if you use the backend: 'MediaElement' option.

In the [options](http://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/options.html) it says the default `backend` is `WebAudio`, where `MediaElement` is a fallback for unsupported browsers. I think it's not necessary to set it.

Comment: thanks for returning friend, have you used this library before? could you tell me better the purpose of the backend in the configuration?

because in the documentation it says that it is necessary to pre-render the audio, and sorry for my terrible english

Comment: I've not used this library before. I just checked the documentation and updated my answer.